# Java : Object escape by Iterator and innerclass

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading the book `Java Concurrency in Practice`.
In **Chapter 4.2** - *Instance Confinement* it says Confined objects can also escape by publishing others such as iterators or innerclass instances that may indirectly publish the confined objects.
Can someone give an example (code) on each please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, here are two examples.
**Iterator:**

```
public class NonSafe {
    private List x;

    public Iterator getIterator() {
        return x.iterator();
    }
}
```

Even though `x` is private, you can still perform operations, such as `delete()`, on its `Iterator`, modifying `x`.

**Inner class:**

```
public class Outer {
    private Object x;

    class Inner {
        public Object lookAtOuter() {
            return Outer.this.x;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, an escaped reference to `Inner`, causes an indirect reference to `x` to leak out, even though it is private.

Comment: I am wondering will making a defensive copy solve the issue in this case or not ?

Comment: @user1389813: A copy usually does the trick. Be careful though, simply making a copy of a collection such as a `List` is not enough, you will have to perform a deep copy (copy the elements too) to make everything absolutely safe.